# how to read 20 march 2011 date in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to read 20 march 2011 date using worddatx32. format but it cant read it gives an error was not found or could not be loaded.

I also try anydtdte32. but it give . in output

how can I read 20 march 2011 date in data lines

```
data sample;
infile datalines truncover dsd;
input JDate : worddatx32.;
format JDate date9.;
datalines; 
20 march 2011
;
run;
```

Comment: data sample;
infile datalines truncover dsd;
input JDate : worddatx32.;
format JDate date9.;
datalines; 
20 march 2011
;
run;

Comment: Show the code you have and the exact input (or exact error message), so we get something reproducible. Please put that information in the question itself, not in comments (only)

Comment: input JDate : anydtdte.;

Comment: I used that option but it gave dot(.) in viewtable

Comment: Don't use the `:` modifier. That is telling SAS to only read to the first space.

Comment: ok but after removing : it gives same result

Answer (score 0):

`WORDDATX.` is a FORMAT and you need an INFORMAT.  Try using `ANYDTDTE.` as the informat.

```
data test ;
  input xx anydtdte32. ;
  format xx date9.;
  put xx= @15 _infile_;
cards;
20 march 2016
20MAR2016
;
```

Also if you are going to use the `:` modifier then SAS will stop at the space and only read the `20`.  Add the `&` modifier and it will stop when it sees two or more spaces.  Of if you are using delimited input then just use an INFORMAT statement.

```
data test ;
  infile cards dsd truncover ;
  input xx ;
  informat xx anydtdte. ;
  format xx date9.;
  put xx= @15 _infile_;
cards;
20 march 2016
20MAR2016
;
```

**NOTE: The ANYDTDTE. informat does not support this format before SAS version 9.4**

If you cannot use the informat then read the value as three fields and convert it yourself.

```
input d $ m $ y $ ;
date = input(cats(d,substr(m,1,3),y),date9.);
```

Comment: sorry it also gives the same result

Comment: dot(.) for 1st record and 2nd record is correct 20MAR2016

Comment: and I also try with & in place of :

Comment: Did you try the sample program I posted? What version of SAS are you using?  Works with SAS 9.4.  Perhaps your data file has something other than spaces?  'A0'X perhaps? or it has a tab, carraige return or other non-printing character after the year?

Comment: yes I was trying with you posted program but got same result

Comment: and I am using sas 9.3

Comment: For more details on the ANYDTDTE. and related informats, see ["One informat to rule them all,"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2016/11/11/anydtdte-informat-read-any-date-sas.html) which also links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Tom's solution doesn't work on your machine... Here's another possibility:

```
data mydates;
  infile datalines dsd truncover delimiter=" ";
  informat day 8.
           month $3.
           year 8.;
  format mydate date9.;
  input day month year;
  mydate = input(cats(day, month, year),date9.);
datalines;
20 march 2016
18 december 16
;
```

[image: Output dataset]

Comment: You seem to be using an INFORMAT statement to do the work of a LENGTH statement. When using list mode INPUT statement like in your program SAS will ignore the lengths set in your informats and use the length of the values that is sees in the data line when reading the values.  But because there is a side effect having the first reference to the variable MONTH be in the assignment of the $3. informat to it SAS will have created the variable as length $3 and so ignore the other characters it reads from the input stream.